# StudentGrades.java:61: error: class, interface, or enum expected

Tags: enums

Here is the code:

```
/*Purpose of program:
•  To demonstrate creating a Student class and creating and using a Student object
•  To demonstrate creating arrays and initializing the array from a data file
•  To demonstrate various ways to utilize arrays
*/

public class StudentGrades
{                       //fields
    private int idNum;                  //1    number to refernce student from list            
    private int[] scores = new int[10]; //2    test grades

    //constructor, accepts args(for fields?)
    public StudentGrades(int mIdNum, int[] mScores)
    {                     
        idNum = mIdNum;                 
        scores = mScores;    
    }

    //(no-args constructor)
    public StudentGrades()   
    {                    
        idNum = 0;
        scores = 0;
    }

    //methods  (sets~ accept args)(gets~ return)
    public void setIdNum(int mIdNum) //1   //allows value change of field after object creation
    {
        idNum = mIdNum;                  
    }   
    public int getIdNum()
    {
        return idNum;
    }  
        public void setScores(int mScores) //2
    {
        scores = mScores;
    } 
    public int getScores()
    {
        return scores;
    }

    public int calculateTotalScores()     //method calculates total of test grades   
    {                                                
        totalScores = totalScores + scores;
        return totalScores;
    } 

    public int calculateAdjustedTotalScores()    //method calculates adjusted total (drop lowest, use highest twice)
    {
        lowest = scores[0];
        highest = scores[ ];
        total = 0;
        for(int c=1; c<scores.length; c++)
            if(lowest >scores[c])
            {
                lowest = scores[c]
            }
        if(highest <scores[c])
        {
            highest = scores[c]
        }
        AdjustedTotalScores = total + lowest - highest           
    }
    // public int calculateTotalScores()    //method calculates average of ten grades (base upon adjusted total, round to the nearest int)
}
```

> ```
> ----jGRASP exec: javac -g StudentGrades.java
> ```
>
> StudentGrades.java:57: error: class, interface, or enum expected
>
> ```
> public int[] calculateAdjustedTotalScores()    //method calculates adjusted total (drop lowest, use highest twice)
>        ^
> ```
>
> StudentGrades.java:60: error: class, interface, or enum expected
>
> ```
> highest = scores[ ];
> ^
> ```
>
> StudentGrades.java:61: error: class, interface, or enum expected
>
> ```
> total = 0;
> ^
> ```
>
> StudentGrades.java:62: error: class, interface, or enum expected
>
> ```
> for(int c=1; c<scores.length; c++)
> ^
> ```
>
> StudentGrades.java:62: error: class, interface, or enum expected
>
> ```
> for(int c=1; c<scores.length; c++)
>              ^
> ```
>
> StudentGrades.java:62: error: class, interface, or enum expected
>
> ```
> for(int c=1; c<scores.length; c++)
>                               ^
> ```
>
> 6 errors
>
> ```
> ----jGRASP wedge2: exit code for process is 1.
> ----jGRASP: operation complete.
> ```

Comment: I do not understand the error responses of the compliler.

Comment: 1. Indent your code. 2. when you declare that a method returns an `int` - it should return an `int` ;)

Answer (score 0):

One of the main issues is when you set up your for loop, you don't use any curly braces.

Additionally, you try to set scores = to 0 at one point. I could be wrong, but I don't think you can set an array of ints to equal a single int.